# How can I get the row index number for particular name(s)?

Tags: r, row, r-rownames

How can one determine the row index-numbers corresponding to particular row names? I have a vector of row names, and I would like to use these to obtain a vector of the corresponding row indices in a matrix.

I tried `row()` and `as.integer(rownames(matrix.object))`, but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to `which`, you can look at `match`:

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5, dimnames = list(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]))
vec <- c("e", "a", "c")
match(vec, rownames(m))
# [1] 5 1 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `which`:

```
which(rownames(matrix.object) %in% c("foo", "bar"))
```

Comment: You'll get the same answer if you use `c("foo", "bar")` or `c("bar", "foo")`. I really think `match` is the correct answer, assuming row names are unique.

Comment: @flodel: You are right. My answer doesn't preserve the order of the names.